# How to automatically multiply and add some coefficient to a data frame in R?

Tags: r, loops

I have this data set

```
obs <- data.frame(replicate(8,rnorm(10, 0, 1)))
```

and this coefficients

```
coeff <- data.frame(replicate(8,rnorm(2, 0, 1)))
```

For each column of obs, I need to multiply the first element of first column, and add the second element of the first column too. I need to do the same for the 8 columns. I read somewhere that if someone copy and paste code more than once you are doing something wrong... and that's exactly what I did.

```
obs.transformed.X1 <-(obs[1]*coeff[1,1])+coeff[2,1]
obs.transformed.X2 <-(obs[2]*coeff[1,2])+coeff[2,2]
       .
       .
       .
       .
       . 
obs.transformed.X8  <-(obs[8]*coeff[1,8])+coeff[2,8]
```

I know there is a smarter way to do this (loop?), but I just couldn't figure it out. Any help will be appreciated.

This is what I've tried but I am only getting the last column

```
for (i in 1:length(obs)) {
    results=(obs[i]*coeff[1,i])+coeff[2,i]
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

I came up with this solution..

```
results = list()
for (seq_along(obs)) {
        results[[i]]=(obs[i]*coeff[1,i])+coeff[2,i]
}

results <- as.data.frame(results)
```

Is there any efficient way to do this?

Comment: For-loops are efficient if the algorithm inside is efficient. You could improve efficiency slightly by making an assignment directly to results[[1]], than using an intermediate vector.

Answer (score 2):

If you coerce to matrix class you can use the sweep function in a sequential fashion first multiplying columns by the first row of coeff and then by adding hte second row, again column-wise:

```
obs <- data.frame(matrix(1:60, 10))  # I find checking with random numbers difficult
coeff <- data.frame(matrix(1:12,2))
sweep( 
   sweep(as.matrix(obs), 2, as.matrix(coeff)[1,], "*"), # first operation is "*"
           2, as.matrix(coeff)[2,], "+" )   # arguments for the addition
 #--------------------------------
      X1 X2  X3  X4  X5  X6
 [1,]  3 37 111 225 379 573
 [2,]  4 40 116 232 388 584
 [3,]  5 43 121 239 397 595
 [4,]  6 46 126 246 406 606
 [5,]  7 49 131 253 415 617
 [6,]  8 52 136 260 424 628
 [7,]  9 55 141 267 433 639
 [8,] 10 58 146 274 442 650
 [9,] 11 61 151 281 451 661
[10,] 12 64 156 288 460 672
```

Decreased number of columns because your original code was too wide for my Rstudio console. But this should be very general. I suspect there's an equivalent matrix operator method but It didn't come to me

Comment: As I said above, it's perhaps more elegant than a for-loop but if I were betting on efficiency, I would choose your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I used `Map`

```
results <- as.data.frame(Map(`+`, Map(`*`, obs, coeff[1,]), coeff[2,]))
```

This should also give what you are looking for.

Comment: But Map and lapply are just for-loops in disguise.